# Issue with Batch File for FFmpeg Video Frame Extraction

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg

Issue

```
[swscaler @ 0000019531bb00c0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
Output #0, image2, to 'temp_frames/frame%08d.jpg':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41
    encoder         : Lavf60.11.100
  Stream #0:0(eng): Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, progressive), 3840x2160 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2023-09-29T13:37:07.000000Z
      handler_name    : ?Mainconcept Video Media Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : Lavc60.26.100 mjpeg
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
[image2 @ 000001951c61b980] Could not open file : temp_frames/frame00000001.jpg
[vost#0:0/mjpeg @ 000001951c603e80] Error submitting a packet to the muxer: I/O error
[out#0/image2 @ 000001951cb8ee80] Error muxing a packet
[out#0/image2 @ 000001951cb8ee80] video:389kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=1.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:00.24 bitrate=N/A speed=1.03x
Conversion failed!
```

I've noticed that using an escape code '%%' for the '%' character, as suggested for similar issues, resolves the problem:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -qscale:v 1 -qmin 1 -qmax 1 -vsync 0 tmp_frames/frame%%08d.jpg
```

However, the same issue occurs even when the command is used within a drag&drop batch file:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM Check if an MP4 file was dragged onto the script
if "%~1"=="" (
    echo Drag an MP4 file onto this script to begin frame extraction.
    pause
    exit /b
)

REM Extract frames from the MP4 file
ffmpeg -i "%~1" -qscale:v 1 -qmin 1 -qmax 1 -vsync 0 temp_frames/frame%%08d.jpg

echo Extraction complete.
pause
```

This is essentially the same code, but it doesn't work as expected within the batch file. Can anyone provide insight into why this issue is occurring and how to resolve it within the batch file context?

Comment: Based on the `Could not open file : temp_frames/frame00000001.jpg` error, does the `temp_frames` folder exist?

Comment: yes, it does exist

Comment: You're going to want to double-check that you're in the folder you think you're in, because I tested your code and got the same error until I created a folder called `temp_frames`. Add the line `echo %cd%` right before the `ffmpeg` command to confirm that you're in the correct directory.

Answer (score 1):

There could be used the following batch file stored for example in the directory `%USERPROFILE%` with the file name `ExtractFrames.cmd`:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

REM Check if the batch file is called with at least one non-empty argument string.
if "%~1" == ""  echo INFO: Drag an MP4 file onto this script to begin frame extraction.& pause & exit /B

REM Create the subdirectory temp_frames in the directory of the video file.
md "%~dp1temp_frames" 2>nul
if not exist "%~dp1temp_frames\" echo ERROR: Could not create the directory: "%~dp1temp_frames"& pause & exit /B 2

REM Extract frames from the MP4 file.
ffmpeg.exe -i "%~1" -qscale:v 1 -qmin 1 -qmax 1 -vsync 0 "%~dp1temp_frames\frame%%08d.jpg"
if errorlevel 1 rd "%~dp1temp_frames" 2>nul & echo ERROR: Failed to extract the frames from: "%~1"& pause & exit /B 1

echo Extraction complete.
pause
endlocal
```

The batch file first checks if it is called without an argument string or with the empty argument string `""`. If this condition is true, there is output a small usage information and the batch processing is paused until the user presses any key and then the batch file processing is exited with exit code 0.

There is created next in the directory according to passed argument string a subdirectory `temp_frames` with redirecting the error output to device **NUL** in case of that directory creation fails because of directory already existing, or the user does not have the permissions to create a subdirectory in that directory, or the passed argument string is invalid at all, etc. It is verified if a subdirectory `temp_frames` finally exists in the directory according to passed argument string. Otherwise an appropriate error message is output by the batch script and batch processing is paused until the user presses any key and then the batch file processing is exited with exit code 2 indicating this type of error to parent process.

Next is executed *FFMPEG* with the passed argument string expecting that this is a file name of a video file with an absolute or a relative path. The fully qualified file name of *FFMPEG* (drive + path + name + extension) enclosed in `"` would be even better than just using file name + extension of *FFMPEG* if the storage location of `ffmpeg.exe` is well known. There could be used `"%~dp0ffmpeg.exe"` if *FFPMEG* executable is for sure always stored in the same directory as the batch file.

The frame extraction process could fail, for example on passed argument string is a directory name, or a file name of a file being not a video file at all, etc. *FFMPEG* outputs an error message in this case and exits with an exit code greater or equal 1 on an error occurred. In this error case is removed the directory `temp_frames` on being empty with redirecting the error message to device **NUL** on not being empty or missing permissions to delete this subdirectory. There is output on an error additionally an error message and the batch processing is paused until the user presses any key and then the batch file processing is exited with exit code 1 indicating a frame extraction error to the parent process.

There is output a short success message on frame extraction process was successful and the batch processing is paused until the user presses any key before restoring the initial execution environment as done implicit also by `cmd.exe` on execution of command `exit` with option `/B` and the exit code value.

The batch file should not be used directly. There should be created now a shortcut file (`.lnk` file) with name `Extract Frames.lnk`.

1. Start *Windows File Explorer* and browse to file `cmd.exe` in the directory `%SystemRoot%\System32` which expands usually to `C:\Windows\System32`.
2. Click with secondary (usually right) pointing device (mouse) button on the file `cmd.exe` to open the context menu for the *Windows Command Processor* which is processing batch files like the above one.
3. Click with primary (usually left) pointing device (mouse) button on the item **Show more options** on Windows 11 and click next on any Windows in submenu **Send to** on the context menu item **Desktop (create shortcut)**.
4. Minimize the *Windows File Explorer* window to see your desktop with the new shortcut file with name `cmd.exe` or `cmd.exe - Shortcut` depending on version of Windows. The file extension `.lnk` is not displayed by Windows.
5. Click with secondary pointing device button on the newly created shortcut file and (after clicking on **Show more options on Windows 11**) click on context menu item **Rename** to change the name of the shortcut file to something meaningful like `Extract Frames`. The name of the shortcut file is later the name of a context menu item in context submenu **Send to**. The file extension `.lnk` is not displayed and not changed during the file rename operation.
6. Click with secondary pointing device button on the newly created and already renamed shortcut file and click on the context menu item **Properties** to open **Properties** dialog window for the shortcut.
7. Modify the property **Target** by appending a space character and `/D /C "%USERPROFILE%\ExtractFrames.cmd"` or whatever is the fully qualified file name of the batch file.
8. There should be entered also a meaningful **Comment**. There can be selected a nice icon after clicking on the button **Change Icon...** displayed later in the context submenu **Send to**. The file `C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll` contains lots of nice icons.
9. There can be of course all other properties on the other tabs configured to whatever you like before closing the dialog window with button **OK** for saving all changed properties and closing the window.

That is the big advantage of using a shortcut file instead of directly the batch file. There can be a nice icon selected and there can be defined the font, font size, number of rows and columns, the text color and the background color, and much more which is all not possible on dragging a file name on a batch file somewhere stored for being easily accessible from a *Windows File Explorer* window.

Cut the modified shortcut file with <kbd>Ctrl+X</kbd>, restore the *Windows File Explorer* window, browse to the directory `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo` and paste with <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> the shortcut file `Extract Frames.lnk` in this directory.
Hint: Enter `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo` in the address bar of the *Windows File Explorer* window and press key <kbd>RETURN</kbd> or <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to open this folder.

There can be clicked with secondary pointing device button now in *Windows File Explorer* (or any other file manager with *Explorer* context menu support) on an MP4 video file for opening the context menu and (after clicking on **Show more options on Windows 11**) clicking in submenu **Send to** on the context menu item `Extract Frames` (name of the shortcut file). Then *explorer.exe* (or any other file manager executable) starts the *Windows Command Processor* to process the specified batch file with the clicked file name in file manager appended as additional argument passed by `cmd.exe` to the batch file.

It would be of course also possible to replace all `%~dp1temp_frames` by `%~dp0temp_frames` for extracting the files always in a subdirectory `temp_frames` in the batch file directory which would be `%USERPROFILE%\temp_frames` on following the instructions in first sentence. There can be used also any other absolute directory path.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `call /?`
- `cmd /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `exit /?`
- `if /?`
- `md /?`
- `pause /?`
- `rd /?`
- `rem /?`
- `setlocal /?`

See also:

- [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) for an explanation of the unconditional command operator `&`.
- The Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul`.